# Which skills are required for a tester with only one year of experience

Tags: qa-role

I am asking about what skills should a test engineer with one year test experience have?

Comment: You should add some context to the question to get a better answer.
Are hiring? looking for a job with one year experience behind you? just finished school?

Comment: Required by who or what? Without that information the question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter for how many years a person works as a software tester. He/she must be,

1. Critical thinker
2. Keen observer
3. Good at bug advocacy
4. Ever learning
5. Able to adapt, improvise and overcome hurdles
6. Able to extract domain knowledge from team, and other resources

And the list may go on and on depending on how many people add to it

Answer (score 1):

According to me 1 year experienced tester should have following skills :

1 - Create test case

2 - Create test scenario

3 - Able to understand requirements easily

4 - Should be capable to use any good bug tracking system [Depends on company 
where tester works]

5 - Analysis skill improvement

6 - Bug life cycle understanding

7 - Software life cycle understanding

8 - Theory knowledge of all basic testing concepts and models

Above list is according to me. Each and every company has diff. requirements and diff. expectation when they hire tester so May be there can be like above or diff.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, these skills are important:

1. Flexibility: Tester should be flexible enough to take up any task. Example, one should be able to work on manual, automation and other types of testing (mixed roles).
2. Knowledge (1-2 years): In terms of knowledge, other answers have covered most of the aspects (SDLC, STLC, QA Processes, Defect life cycle, Analytical Skills, Test Cases and Test Scenario, Quality Center).
3. Good Communication Skills: This is a plus point if the role requires interacting with the client.
4. Team player & learning attitude: Self-explanatory. One should continuously develop their skills.
5. Domain Knowledge (1 year old?): 1 year is good enough to get some basic domain knowledge (HR, Banking, Insurance. etc)
6. Certifications - Again this is just a plus point (probably Istqb).

Answer (score 0):

This is very subjective and depending on the job and product, but there are some essential skills.

**Basic development skills**

Understanding the life of a developer is import to be able to connect to them and really assist them. Secondly automation of tests is becoming ever more important in a world with a focus on continuous delivery.

**Quick learner**

From new tools, applications, techniques and of-course domain knowledge. You need to be able to truly understand requirements and adapt quickly to the changing world around you.

**Loose the ego**

Testers have no value for ego, be able to clearly communicate with developers, clients, managers. You are here to assist them in improving quality from requirements until delivery.

If you have these three you will probably have a great career as a Software Test Engineering.